Why am I facing difficulties with VBA in Excel when writing keys and values from a dictionary?
I want to write the keys and values of a dictionary to cells in an Excel worksheet called dash. However, when I run the code below, it only writes nome1 in column 20 without its corresponding value. When I run the code for the second time, it fills in all the data correctly.
What is the reason for this happening, and what would be a possible solution?

Sub escreverDicionario()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim wsdash As Worksheet
    Dim linha_inicial As Long
    Dim chave As Variant

    ' Definir a planilha de destino
    Set wsdash = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dash")
    
    ' Criar o dicionário
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Adicionar dados ao dicionário
    dict.Add "nome1", "valor1"
    dict.Add "nome2", "valor2"
    dict.Add "nome3", "valor3"
    
    ' Inicializar linha_inicial para 1
    linha_inicial = 1
    
    ' Loop para escrever os dados no Excel
    For Each chave In dict.Keys
        wsdash.Cells(linha_inicial, 20).Value = chave
        wsdash.Cells(linha_inicial, 21).Value = dict(chave)
        
        ' Avançar para a próxima linha
        linha_inicial = linha_inicial + 1
    Next chave
End Sub

I want it to write correctly from the first execution of the code, or suggest another possible solution.

Works for me (when running the first time) and sounds very odd. Have you tried to debug you code? Check with the debugger if the values in the dictionary are set correctly.

As you can see, the code works as expected. First of all, try to save and close the workbook and quit Excel. If that doesn't help, share if there is an error (number and description). Let us know if this resolves the issue. Do you have an event active? (e.g. Worksheet_Change)

First try        wsdash.Cells(linha_inicial, 20).Value = 1         wsdash.Cells(linha_inicial, 21).Value = 2

Check Application.ScreenUpdating = False/True settings. It looks like your program is changing the ScreenUpdating state and not going back. Therefore, after 1 time, a state alternation is obtained.

Application.ScreenUpdating is not "sticky" - it automatically reset to True when code execution ends.

Please edit your post to include screen shots of the outputs for both correct and incorrect.  Given the code is working (filling in appropriately cells 1, 20; 1, 21; 2, 20; 2, 21; 3, 20; 3,21, for persons reviewing the question), it is possible that your specific output could be the key to resolving your issue.

The OP's original code executes perfectly on my machine.  It is possible that the workbook is corrupt or possibly the cells font color matches it's interior color.
I just wanted to show an alternative way to dump the key/value pairs.
Sub escreverDicionario()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim wsdash As Worksheet
    Dim linha_inicial As Long
    Dim chave As Variant

    ' Definir a planilha de destino
    Set wsdash = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dash")
    
    ' Criar o dicionário
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Adicionar dados ao dicionário
    dict.Add "nome1", "valor1"
    dict.Add "nome2", "valor2"
    dict.Add "nome3", "valor3"
    
    With wsdash
        .Cells(1, 20).Resize(dict.Count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
        .Cells(1, 21).Resize(dict.Count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
    End With
End Sub

